# Cannot access '<init>': it is protected in 'Entry'

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to access the dataset

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry

    //Create a dataset
    val dataArray = ArrayList<Entry>()
    dataArray.add(Entry(38f))
    dataArray.add(Entry(14f))
    dataArray.add(Entry(14f))
    dataArray.add(Entry(34f))
    val dataSet = PieDataSet(dataArray, "")
    dataSet.valueTextSize=20f
    dataSet.valueTextColor=Color.WHITE
```

but that result's into an error.

```
**Cannot access '<init>': it is protected in 'Entry'**
```

Why isn't it working? How can this be workaround.

Comment: `<init>` is the internal name for a constructor; the error is telling you that you can't call an `Entry` constructor. (And since your code calls only the constructor which takes a single `Float` param, it's clear which constructor it's talking about.) You'll need to find some other way of getting `Entry` instances. Does `Entry` have any other constructors, which are public? Does it have any static methods which return an instance? If not, the library will almost certainly provide some other way to get `Entry`s, so check its docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use MPAndroidChart, but a quick glance at the Github page shows that Entry requires two floats passed to the constructor for X and Y. Since you're making a PieChart, I think you need to use PieEntry instead, which takes a single float passed to the constructor.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue. :)